I can't save the changes in the Datagrip procedure
the problem is when opening a procedure and making changes to it, I get an error when trying to save the procedure.The procedure has no errors.
enter image description here
if you do the same thing in Dbeaver, everything works.
I can also save changes in the datagrid if I apply the changes via the console
create or replace, but this is not so convenient, I would like to be able to change the procedure in itself
nothing, I have no idea what can affect this behavior. I don't even remember, but it seems to me that everything worked at first, but I'm not sure
upd:
The case turned out to be in the DatabaseHelper plugin, I got an error related to it when trying to change the "Reader mode" settings. I deleted the plugin, decided to check at the same time the ability to save the procedure and the miracle it worked. maybe it will be useful to someone
enter image description here

There is no error on your first screenshot. Also, make sure that you read this tutorial:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2022/03/15/working-with-source-code-in-datagrip/
